# Create one-time ssh keys over the web

Tags: ssh

A lot of times, I need to ssh from computers that are not mine, so for security reasons, I would like to be able to create an ssh key that expires after one log-in with it.
Also, it would be helpful if I would be able to retrieve these from my web server by entering in a password.
Not so sure about how well the web server aspect of this would work, because that would probably pose a whole new set of security risks, but even just being able to create one-time ssh keys would be helpful.
If anyone can help with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is interesting and wouldn't take too long to implement. The service could generate an ordinary RSA or ECDSA key (using `ssh-keygen` or `openssl`), append the public part to `authorized_keys` (with an "auto-expire" comment), and your `~/.profile` or `sshrc` could automatically clean up such keys upon logging in.

However, it would you give **no advantage** in security, since you still have to authenticate, this time to a website – using, presumably, the same username and plain-text password that you would have given to SSH...

Even if you use SSL to avoid transferring the password in plain-text, the website still remains a little **less** secure than direct SSH logins; you would have to obtain and periodically renew a verified SSL certificate in order to avoid MitM attacks, and it is not as easy as just carrying the SSH fingerprint in your pocket.)

---

Before you suggest that you could use some kind of OTP authentication for the website, I'll note that you can use OTP for SSH connections, too. In particular, [Google Authenticator](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/) comes with a PAM module for your server and OTP generator apps for most popular mobile phones. Another service, [Duo Security](http://www.duosecurity.com/), uses a phone call to authenticate. Finally, standalone modules such as OPIE exist, too.

Answer (score 1):

So how do you make sure that the access to the web server is safe?

A one-time password system developed by Cambridge University: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/otpw.html